# I am trying to checked the checkbox default when page is loading using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to checked the checkbox default when  page is loading. This is my
component.

```
var user = ViewprojectComponent.featuresList1;
this.rules_id = user[0];
for(let i = 0; i <= this.rules_id.length; i++)
{
  var checkedOn1 = this.rules_id[i];
  this.Rules = checkedOn1.rule_id;
  this.checkedOn.push(this.Rules)
}
```

and HTML is

```html
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rule *ngFor="let feature of checkedOn">
  <tr>{{feature}}
    <td><input type="checkbox" [checked]="feature == rule.rule_id " (change)="selectRule($event, rule.rule_id)"></td>
    <td>{{rule.rule_name}}</td>
    <td><button (click)="viewRule(rule.rule_id)" class="mini ui green button">
                    View </button></td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Some coding practice advice - 1) You should avoid using **var** instead use **let**. 2) You should avoid using component name to get the data from it. `ViewprojectComponent.featuresList1;` not a good practice. 
Coming to your question. So what are you getting wrong?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion .i need to check the checkbox based on backend data ,if i found the data for check box then it should checked automatically

Comment: Are you getting the rule_name correctly in your html?

Comment: Yes i am getting  both rule_name and rule_id

Comment: Please show the featuresList1 json you are using.

Answer (score 1):

you can declare the default value of check box true.

```html
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="theCheckbox"  data-md-icheck (change)="toggleVisibility($event)"/>
    Checkbox is <span *ngIf="marked">checked</span><span *ngIf="!marked">unchecked</span>

  <span class="checkmark"></span>
```

```html
export class AppComponent  {

  marked = true;
  theCheckbox = true;
  constructor() {
  }
  
  toggleVisibility(e){
    this.marked= e.target.checked;
  }
```

Comment: Above answer not current for my solution